# jQuery Validation check box

Tags: jquery, validation

How make show validator mesage for checkbox not selected?

I have this code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="term" />
```

What code put in jQuery?

Comment: Try this: http://bit.ly/zovuvx

Answer (score 0):

you can write the following code for checking whether checkbox is selected or not..

```
if($('input:checkbox[name=term]').is(':checked')) {
    alert('checked'); } else {
    alert('not checked'); }
```